# Remove double appendix header [Article Class]

Tags: appendices, article

My problem is that I cant get  rid of one of the double appendix headers , if I try to use

```
\section*{}
```

My equation numerbs no longer have A1, A2 ,B1, B2 etc since I use

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

[image]

Here is my preamble

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{eqnarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}


\begin{document}

blablabla

\newpage

\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendix A}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{appendices}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\appendix` before your appendix sections and remove the `appendices` environment.

Comment: Don't call your appendices appendix. It is obvious to the reader be the alpabetic numbering. Call them *Additional figures*,  or blueprints, charts, etc.

Comment: Then I get `A Appendix A` `B Appendix B`

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for the table of contents: Use `\section[]{Appendix A}`. The optional argument is used as section name in the table of contents, so if you set it to empty you'll get simply `Appendix A` instead of `Appendix A Appendix A`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
\section[]{Appendix A}

\begin{equation}
    a=b
\end{equation}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that did not work with my equations in appendix A

Comment: I updated my solution to show the numbering of the equations. It works in this minimal example, and also if I include all the packages from the code sample in your question. Please have a look on your code again what else could cause a problem with the numbering.

Comment: @asdf: `did not work` is no helpful description